# How to modify or remove addSuccess message in Magento?

Tags: magento

For example, the following action will add a message which will be inserted into the page:

-When addtocart button is clicked, it will display a message saying the product was added successful or not.
The code is in app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartControllers.php

```
$message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()));
$this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
```

-When a product review is submitted, there will be a message saying the review has been accepted for moderation.
The code is in app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php

```
$session->addSuccess($this->__('Your review has been accepted for moderation.'));
```

The above two are just examples, there are more other similar messages which are display on certain actions.

I know how to override it, change or remove the message. For the addtocart message, it can also be turned off by going to the Admin Panel.

I believe there is a better way to modify those messages than create a module and overriding the function just for modifying the message or remove it.

**Does anyone know any better ways to modify or remove those addSuccess messages?
How can we modify or remove those messages after addSuccess() function is already called and the messages are added?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course there's a better way ;D

Take a look into your `app/locale/en_US` folder (or whichever language you want to edit). There you'll find a series of CSV files with translations.

Every time you see `echo $this->_('Something Here');` it means there is a translation in these CSV files. This depends on the current namespace, so for Checkout messages, you'd want to look in `Mage_Checkout.csv` first.

Open with your favorite text editor and look for something like this:
`%s was added to your shopping cart.,%s was added to your shopping cart.`

Now, change the line AFTER the comma to what you would like it to be:
`%s was added to your shopping cart.,We just added %s to your cart!`

Alternatively, you can make it blank by just removing everything after the comma:
`%s was added to your shopping cart.,`

The `%s` denotes the variable used, which is passed as the second parameter in the `_()` function.

Comment: Thanks. This works if I just want to modify the message, but if I remove the message the way you suggested, it emptied the message, but the ul element of the class="message" is still showing up after the addtocart button is clicked. The ul element will show up as a colored line instead of a message in a colored box.How can remove the message and also remove the ul element that contains the message?

Comment: Well, that would depend, you may be able to remove it using Javascript/JQuery (check if it is empty, and if so, remove the UL element), or you can change the CSS around to the point where it doesn't show it at all. Other than those two other solutions, you'll have to resort to editing template or code files.

Comment: If I still need to use css, then I can use css to hide it without changing the language file, template file or the code files. So, it goes back to the original questions, which of the following is a better solution for this task: 1. override the function in php controller file. 2. change the language file and then use css to hide the empty ul element. 3. user only css. 4. Is there any other better ways to do this

Comment: The message class is used for other things as well, if you hide it completely then you wont see any messages that use the class. Other than these solutions, you can edit the template .phtml files to prevent the message from being output, you don't need to touch any classes.

Comment: If I modify the class, I will only need to override the function that generates this message. Other messages can still be shown because not every pop up messages are generated from this function of this class. If to modify the .phtml file, this will prevent other messages to be shown because this .phtml is used by more than one parent template files.

Comment: In case anybody wants to remove these messages globally, add this to your `local.xml` in the 'layout' directory:

     `<default translate="label" module="page">
        <label>All Pages</label>
        <remove name="global_messages" />
        ...
      </default>`

Answer (score 1):

This should remove all success or error messages from your session.

```
$this->_getSession()->getMessages(true);
```

More specifically, you can use the following to remove messages from `core` and `customer` session respectively:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getMessages(true);
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getMessages(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

> For the addtocart message, it can also be turned off by going to the Admin Panel.

As @s-hunter said the above quote, can any one tell where to find the setting to turn it off.